# A value of type 'T?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T'

Tags: dart

I am trying to assign to an `int` value, however, I get this error:

```
A value of type 'int?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'
```

The line causing this compile-time error is the following:

```dart
int number = someFunction();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the value returned from `someFunction` is **nullable** and trying to assign that value to a ***non*-nullable** variable is a compile-time error (null-safety was introduced in Dart `2.7`).

You need to *check for null* using a `!= null` condition.

### Example

```dart
void exampleFunction<T>(T? input) {
  T result = input; // <- ERROR here

  print(result);
}
```

In this example, `input` is **nullable** and thus cannot be assigned to the ***non*-nullable** variable `result`.

### Solution

The given example problem can be solved like this:

```dart
void exampleFunction<T>(T? input) {
  if (input != null) {
    T result = input;

    print(result); 
  }
}
```